# How can I fix Ecconrefused error in node.js?

Tags: node.js

The module I use gives this error even if the server is turned on. I have hidden my IP address, but you can understand. I attach the error I received as a photo.
What I want to do: I'm trying to get server information from a FiveM API. When I try to get data from the server running on the correct IP and port number in localhost, it gives this error and reacts as if the server is closed.

[My error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YrhQ.jpg)

ECONNREFUSED

Comment: Could you provide some more information  on what you are trying to achieve. What you have told us so far does not provide enough details.

Comment: I'm trying to get server information from a FiveM API. When I try to get data from the server running on the correct IP and port number in localhost, it gives this error and reacts as if the server is close.